# Smoothly change css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, smoothing

my situation is as follows:

I have the following function

```
var showHideMemberContent = function(){
if(isHidden === false){
    $("#showHideMemberContent").text("Member Content");
    $("#main").css("height","-=187");
    $('#mainBottom').hide('slow', function() {
        isHidden = true;
    });
} else {
    $("#showHideMemberContent").text("Verberg");
    $("#main").css("height","+=187");
    $('#mainBottom').show('slow', function() {
        isHidden = false;
    });
}
};
```

So when the function executes it hides the "mainBottom" div. The "main" div should decrease/increase its height.
It does so, but I need to know if there is a way to do this smoothly.

Thanks in regard.

Comment: By "smoothly" you mean you want to see it gradually increase in an [`.animate`d](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) manner, rather than jumping directly to the new size?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, use jquerys `animate()` method, http://api.jquery.com/animate/.

Include jquery ui if you want to use easing types other than "linear" or "swing". Its passed as a second argument (string), to the animate method. https://jqueryui.com/easing/

Example (with jquery ui loaded):

```
$(selector).animate({ height: '200px' }, 'easeInOutCubic', function(){ 
    /* animation comlete */ 
});
```

Also, work on your accept rate.

Comment: The core version of `.animate()` also provides for easing.

Comment: @nnnnnn yes, but only 2 easings afaik, 'swing' & 'linear'

Comment: @MrSlippyFist " can you provide some tips HOW I can work on this". You have a low rate. People with low rates usually dont get help due to that. So either 75% of your answers have been useless, or you need to understand how to define a correct answer. It may be correct even though you may not understand it.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I just accepted an old answer I'd never accepted because I did not understand. Still, the rest of my answers have been useless. Also, thanks for this answer. It works now.

Answer (score 8):

You can use CSS to achieve this. Simply add this rule to your CSS declaration for `#main`:

```
#main {
    -khtml-transition: height 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: height 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: height 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: height 0.3s ease;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.3s ease;
    transition: height 0.3s ease;
}
```

Here the `height` part defines the property to apply the transition to, the `0.3s` defines the time it takes to transition from one state to another, and the `ease` property defines the function for the transition. Ease will slowly accelerate to 50% transition and then decelerate to 100%.

The advantage of using CSS over jQuery's animate function is that the CSS transform is hardware accelerated when supported, and will be smoother and more efficient. The disadvantage is that some antiquated browser versions will not support the effect, however it will simply fall back to a non-animated height change, rather than breaking.

To learn more about CSS transitions, follow the link below to Mozilla's article. They're a great reference for these sort of things and an excellent place to start learning, or even brush up on your knowledge. I've also included an example of this technique below.

[MDN article on transitions.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/css_transitions)

[Here is a jsfiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/xnVqP/1/)

Comment: This is a better answer than the accepted one in my opinion, and it can be applied to multiple elements in the same group rather than just a single element per function call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use animate for that:

```
var oldHeight = $("#main").height();
$("#main").animate({'height', oldHeight + 187}, { duration: 500, queue: false });
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to operate with css and classes, not the style attribute, you can use jquery-ui's `switchClass()` or `toggleClass()` methods http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/switchClass http://jqueryui.com/demos/toggleClass/

Answer (score 0):

Use animate()...

```
var showHideMemberContent = function(){
if(isHidden === false){
    $("#showHideMemberContent").text("Member Content");
    $("#main").animate({height:-=187}, 300);
    $('#mainBottom').hide('slow', function() {
        isHidden = true;
    });
} else {
    $("#showHideMemberContent").text("Verberg");
    $("#main").animate({height:+=187}, 300);
    $('#mainBottom').show('slow', function() {
        isHidden = false;
    });
}
    };
```